# Powershell Script to Download .exe from Azure Blob Storage on Role Start fails: file size is 0KB

Tags: .net, powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

Using the June 2012 version of the SDK and emulator, I'm trying to install the Java runtime executable on an Azure worker role, following this example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Installing-Java-in-Web-94f145dd#content.

I've uploaded the x64 installer as a blob, and renamed it 'Java.exe' (simply to make the file name a little easier on the eye):

[image: Blobs]

When I check with [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/), I can see the blob is there, and that it is the correct size (31MB).

Following the example, I then use this startup task:

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="Run.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
</Startup>
```

To call this command:

```
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file .\Launch.ps1

start /w Java.exe /s
```

Which in turn calls this powershell script:

```
function download_from_storage ($container, $blob, $connection, $destination) {
Add-Type -Path ((Get-Location).Path + '\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll')
$storageAccount = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount]::Parse($connection)
$blobClient = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobClient($storageAccount.BlobEndpoint, $storageAccount.Credentials)   
$remoteBlob = $blobClient.GetBlobReference($container + '/' + $blob)
$remoteBlob.DownloadToFile($destination + "\" + $blob)
}

$connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devstoreaccount1; AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=='

# JRE
$jre = 'Java.exe'
download_from_storage 'startuputil' $jre $connection_string (Get-Location).Path
```

This works, and if I browse to the approot that the emulator creates on my local disk, I can see Java.exe there, but its file size is 0KB, and running it fails with the error 'Not a valid Win32 application'

[image: Empty Java.exe]

Clearly the download is beginning, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be completing. Can anybody tell me why?

I wondered if it was related to this issue: [Exception Downloading Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550005/exception-downloading-azure-blob), but running it against our live storage account fails in exactly the same way.

I should add I'm a reasonably experienced C# programmer, but know very little about powershell, so am more or less following the example line by line. And I'm not really looking for a workaround - it's straightforward enough to package this file by including it in the project and setting it to always copy, but I'm going to need this technique for other, larger files and so would like to get it working if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(converting my comment to an answer)

I believe that error message could mean that the container doesn't exist. Are you sure that "startuputil" is the correct name of the container you created?

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I am a klutz with powershell. Mind you, that error message could be a little more informative...

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying your connection string like this:

```
$connection_string = 'UseDevelopmentStorage=true'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No - it still fails. And as I said above, it also fails if I use our live storage account.

Comment: Huh...that's weird. I basically copied the code from above and ran it as a PowerShell script on my computer instead of running as a start up task in a role. Can you try running Launch.ps1 PowerShell script on its own? Just launch PowerShell console. Navigate to the directory containing this PS file and execute ".\Launch.ps1". That should tell you if there's anything wrong with the PowerShell script.

Comment: Exception calling "DownloadToFile" with "1" argument(s): "One of the request in
puts is out of range."
At D:\Work\CLIENTS\PageEngine\Solutions\PageEngine\Azure\csx\Debug\roles\FontRo
le\approot\Launch.ps1:6 char:31
+     $remoteBlob.DownloadToFile <<<< ($destination + "\" + $blob)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException   -  Not sure if I was meant to start up the role before doing this. I didn't, and got this error.

Comment: This error is coming from the storage client library. It could be because of many reasons but primary reason is one of the parameters is invalid. Can you post the updated PowerShell script?

Comment: I haven't updated the script. Just tried 'UseDevelopmentStorage=true'
and then switched back to the original.

Comment: So I downloaded the project source code from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Installing-Java-in-Web-94f145dd#content and only changed the $connection_string to 'UseDevelopmentStorage=true' in Launch.ps1 in both web and worker role (and also uploaded Java.exe in 'startuputil' like you did). After I ran the application, I got the exe file with proper size. If you want, I can upload the code somewhere.

Comment: I've done exactly the same, but I get the same error: a zero-length file. It's odd - as if perhaps it's a timing issue (role start trying to grab the file before dev storage is ready, even though dev storage is running previously). Anyway - I'm out of time for this evening. I'll try again in the morning and see if I can see what's broken. Many thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @JcFx I believe that error message could mean that the container doesn't exist. Are you sure that "startuputil" is the correct name of the container you created?

Comment: @smarx - that was it. Sorry - I really am a noob when it comes to powershell, and I didn't even notice that.